# Node.js for Stack Overflow clone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, node.js

Would Node.js (which uses a non-blocking I/O) be suitable for building a db driven application like Stack Overflow My understanding is that nb I/O is good when the requests don't take much time and db query could be a time-intensive operation. Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

I guess a better question would be - which would be a better option to build a db driven app (like Stack Overflow), something like node.js or something like RoR/Django/Play? 
I'm asking for the pros and cons of each.

Comment: That makes it a worse question, as it will likely start a flame war.

Comment: @dystroy: please read my question. I didn't ask a generic question like "is xyz a good technology"? I asked if it was suitable for a specific type of application, because I'm unsure if my understanding of its technical limitations is correct. Second part is, if not, would "abc" be a better option. I specifically asked for an objective evaluation weighing pros and cons not an opinion, which is very well within the requirements of a question.

Comment: I want to gain better understanding of their respective strengths and weaknesses. I'll pick the one that I find to be objective and comprehensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, Node.js is suitable for database-driven applications as long as there is a good asynchronous I/O node.js library for your database engine of choice.

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Node-js/What-are-the-ideal-use-cases-of-Node-JS

Comment: Thanks, that clarified things!

Comment: If you are certain that javascript will not be able to keep up with your needs, I wouldn't wouldn't implement the CPU-intensive stuff in javascript.  If you have a many-core/cpu production environment, you can consider having multiple instances of your application running, each using a separate processor.